# Objective-C pointers as booleans

Tags: objective-c, pointers, boolean, evaluation

Going through some documentation on modifying CGImageRef data, I came across a strange example -- It went something along the lines of this pseudocode:

```
void *data = Allocate space for data;
if (data != NULL) Manipulate data;
if (data) Free data;
```

This got me wondering! What is the difference between the boolean operation `if (data != NULL)` and the boolean operation `if (data)`.

To be more specific, how do pointers behave in Objective C when they are treated as booleans? Attempting to google this, I only found myriads of questions relating to pointers-*to*-booleans, as opposed to pointers being evaluated *as* booleans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're exactly the same.  Non-zero values of any type are interpreted as "true" in C, and by extension in Objective-C.  C doesn't even *have* a boolean type.

Comment: Ooh and because NULL can be seen as a pointer to the position 0, it gets evaluated as false... Gotcha, thankyou! :)

Comment: Please, don't think of NULL as anything remotely like "a pointer to the position 0". It's simply the agreed value for pointers that don't point to anything. When forced to be a boolean, it equates to false. And when you force a zero to a pointer, you get NULL.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen: a null pointer isn't necessarily a pointer to memory location 0. According to the C spec, a null pointer is guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid pointer. On some platforms, memory location 0 may be valid (for example, it may be the first entry in a table of interrupt handlers). A null pointer, however, converts to and from integer value 0, whence a null pointer is interpreted as a false value. See C99, § 6.3.2.3 3.

Comment: In fact >=C99 has boolean type defined in [stdbool.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I didn't know that NULL could be internally stored as nonzero! Nevertheless, I find that due to all of these automatic conversions, NULL can still be *thought of* as pointing to the position 0. It's just a simple way of thinking about it, and has no real effect on the process of programming.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen: it can have affects. Though they may be rare, the simplistic view of null pointers can cause bugs. For example, you can access a pointer value directly (which, admittedly, you generally shouldn't do), and your code wouldn't then handle non-null 0 pointers or (worse still) null pointers properly. Better to think of null pointers as having special null values (the concept of "null" and [nullable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type) is useful beyond pointers), like `NULL` in SQL, `None` in Python and `Nothing` in Haskell. Programming is a subtle discipline.

Comment: @outis Ah, I see. Generally, when doing pointer arithmetic, I check for null by using NULL, as opposed to checking for 0. Whether or not I see NULL as zero, it is ALWAYS better practice to use the NAME of what you are referring to. Whenever programming with pointers, I always see them as magic numbers, and never worry about their value (other than equality amongst variables). The idea of seeing null as 0 is just an attempt to alleviate my hate for anonymity. Programming is clearly an idiosyncratic practice, so shall we agree to disagree?